# How can i apply hover in disabled dates in jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery

I want tool tip in my datepicker calender those dates are  disabled. How can i do this?

Please help.

```
var date11=["2014-11-8","2014-11-9"] // disabled dates
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    inline: true,
    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ data11.indexOf(string) == -1]
    console.log(data11.indexOf(string) == -1); 
}
```

});
     });

Comment: you can check disabled dates class name and add hover on it

Comment: i am use this class but still not work....
 $(".ui-state-default").on("mouseenter", function() {
     $(this).attr('title', 'This is the hover-over text');  // title attribute will be shown during the hover
   });

Comment: you need to use disabled date class name and better with jQuery hover();